# SQL exception before Start (with .next())

Tags: java, exception, iterator, resultset

I'm having some bad trouble related to a resulset.
I have one statement, resulset, ... with the very same structure and it works but this one doesn't.
I've seen some people with similar problems but related to the lack of .next(). As you can see, I already have it and I still don't understand.

conex is the Connection, which it's received from the session of a jsp.

Let's see if you can enlight me

```
public String[] getPerfiles(Connection conex) throws SQLException {
    String[] perfiles = {};
    int i = 0;
    Statement st = conex.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery(q.PERFILESQUERY);
    while (rs1.next()) {
        perfiles[i] = rs1.getString(2);
        i++;
    }
    return perfiles;
}
```

The Query

```
    String PERFILESQUERY = "SELECT * FROM perfiles";
```

Here is the error trace

> Exception occurred in target VM: Before start of result set 
>   java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:855)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5773)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5693)
>     at clases.Funciones.getPerfiles(Funciones.java:123)     at
>   org.apache.jsp.formUsuario_jsp._jspService(formUsuario_jsp.java:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)     at

Comment: i thing your query return single record and you are trying fetch more than that.

Comment: This is unrelated to the given exception, but `String[] perfiles = {};` is highly problematic. Adding anything to `perfiles`, even at index 0, will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: so how do i pass the resulset to an array?

Comment: this is the query
    `String PERFILESQUERY = "SELECT * FROM perfiles";`

Comment: At last it was an inocent glitch in other part of the code. **I left an statement opened** so the first query was working but these others weren't. I closed them all after getting the data and _changed the array for an arraylist [just in case]_ and it's **working properly now**.
Thank you all for your help